# Rails 6 routes - proper way of simple nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Because it's been a while since I was using Rails monolith instead of GrapeAPI I've silly question. I want to create a route for path - `users/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports` where I will displays `PortfolioReports.where(status: 'archived')`. I created routes:

```
  namespace :users do
    resources :portfolios, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :archived_report, only: [:index, :show]
      resources :portfolio_report, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
```

So I've got two questions: Should the routes file look like my current routes.rb ? and if I have Portfolio and PortfolioReport models like below, the portfolio_reports_controller should be inside `app/controllers/users/portfolio_reports_controller.rb` or `app/controllers/portfolio_reports_controller.rb` ?

```
  class Portfolio
    has_many :portfolio_reports
  end

  class PortfolioReport
    belongs_to :portfolio
  end
```

Comment: I am not sure if having a path such as `users/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports` makes any sense.  Could it be either `users/1/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports` or just `portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports`

Comment: For now it has to be as `users/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports` but in the near future probably it will be `users/1/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports/archived_reports`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you can use "Shallow Nesting" which basically says to only nest the `index`, `new` and `create` actions under the parent resource. For the other actions you don't need to nest the routes, because through the record itself you have access to the associated record, so there is no need to have the id in the url.

So your routes will be:

```
users/portfolios/                    # Portfolios#index
users/portfolios/1                   # Portfolios#show
users/portfolios/1/portfolio_reports # PortfolioReports#index
users/portfolio_reports/1            # PortfolioReports#show
users/portfolios/1/archived_reports  # ArchivedReports#index
users/archived_reports/1             # ArchivedReports#show
```

And routes.rb should look like this:

```
namespace :users do
  resources :portfolios, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :archived_report, only: [:index]
    resources :portfolio_report, only: [:index]
  end
  resources :archived_report, only: [:show]
  resources :portfolio_report, only: [:show]
  end
```

(If you'd use all 7 routes you could use the helper `shallow` as mentioned in the docs).
No need to nest archived_reports under portfolio_reports like you mentioned in your question!

Find more info on shallow nesting here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

For the `user` namespace:
Your controllers should live in a subfolder `user` because you have the namespace `user`:

```
app/controllers/user/portfolio_reports_controller.rb
```

Comment: Ok, so what should routes.rb look like for `users/portfolio_reports/1 # PortfolioReports#show` and `users/portfolios/1/archived_reports  # ArchivedReports#index` or even for `users/archived_reports/1  # ArchivedReports#show` to achieve routes which you wrote? I see these shallows for the first time in my life tbh

Comment: I updated my answer - as per the docs shallow nesting is used to avoid deep nesting which make the routes long and the route helpers cumbersome.